# My radio button values are only showing the first letter

Tags: php, radio-button, string-concatenation

My Radio Button values are only showing the first letter ([see picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMnok.png)).  I have a form set up with a radio button to choose between "Image Slide" and "Video Slide" but only the first letter from each value is showing up.  Just the "I" and the "V".  Why is this displaying like this?  How can I fix this?

Here is my code with the lines specific to the Radio Button highlighted: http://pastebin.com/sDGTMe6v

Comment: Take a look at the outputted HTML source and first ensure that the PHP is the thing at fault. So look for just a single character printed fr the radio button name.

Comment: I didnt see anything glaring in there. Make sure you're not doing something like echoing out $option['name'][0] in which case a string gets treated like an array and you'll only see the first character.

Comment: i normally get paid for reading and helping debug code that long :) it would help a lot if you removed the "code noise"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in

```
case 'radio':
foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
    echo '<input type="radio" name="', $field['id'], '" value="', $option['value'], '"', $meta == $option['value'] ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />', $option['name'];
}
break;
```

you should be displaying $option, not $option['name'] :

```
case 'radio':
foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
    echo '<input type="radio" name="', $field['id'], '" value="', $option, '"', $meta == $option ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />', $option;
}
break;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure how the object $option is made.  You can debug that, to see how it should work, by adding this line after line 119(inside the foreach function):

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($option).'</pre>';
```

You may not be able to use $option['value'] or it may not be getting parsed correctly.  Once you see the structure of $option you can debug further.

Answer (score 0):

it happens because you try to output

```
$option['name']
```

your `$option` is not an array..

just output

```
$option
```

This should be the same for the value attribute as well.. so `$option['value']` should be `$option` as well